# C: The proper way to refer to a struct though a void pointer

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, void-pointers

I'm trying to insert an element of type Student (definition below) into the field "info" of an structure of type "NoArv" (definition below). 
I NEED to do this through a pointer o type "Base", which is a void-pointer.

I try the code below, but when compiling, I receive the following error message:

```
> base.c:38:19: error: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [-Werror]
>
     if(a.ra < (*p)->info.ra)
>                    ^
> base.c:38:19: error: request for member ‘info’ in something not a structure or union
> 
> base.c:39:16: error: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [-Werror]
>
       *p = (*p)->left;
>
>                 ^
```

**How can I correctly dereference such a pointer to a void type?**

I call the function with this: `InsereBase(&base, student)`

Where "base" is a variable of type **Base** and "student" is an element of type **Student**.

CODE:

```
Boolean InsertBase(Base *p, Student a) {
  while((*p) != NULL){
    if(a.ra < (*p)->info.ra)
      *p = (*p)->left;
    else if(a.ra > (*p)->info.ra)
      *p = (*p)->right;
    else
      return false;
  }

  *p = MALLOC(sizeof(NoArv));
  (*p)->info = MALLOC(sizeof(Student));
  (*p)->info.ra = a.ra;
  (*p)->info.name = a.name;

  (*p)->left = (*p)->right = NULL;

  return true;

}
```

.

```
typedef void * Base; 
typedef char * String;
typedef enum {false, true} Boolean;
```

.

```
typedef struct {
  int ra;
  String name;
  } Student;
```

.

```
typedef struct AuxNoArv {
  Student info;                   
  struct AuxNoArv *left,*right;  
  } NoArv, * ImplBase;
```

Comment: Hiding pointers behind typedefs is the cause of your error.

Comment: You'll need to cast it to the appropriate type before dereferencing it.

Comment: Typedefs or no typedefs, you can't dereference `void *`. You have to convert it to another pointer type first.

Comment: if `p` is a pointer to `Base`, and `Base` is a `void *`, then it's simple: you can't dereference a void pointer. It's just not-done. Illegal. Impossiburu! Can't be done. A void pointer _has_ to be cast to a valid type

Comment: There's also the problem that the `info` element in the `AuxNoArv` structure is not a pointer, so you should not allocate to it.

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand what should I do in this case.
But if you're sugesting to change those typedefs; I cant. This is part os a program with multiple files to be compiled together the typdefs are in a file separated from the one with **InsertBase** function and I have no permission to edit these.

Comment: Also be careful when having two pointers point to the same memory area. If you call `free` on one pointer, the second pointer will be left handing. I'm thinking about the `name` pointer in the `Student` structure.

Comment: `((NoArv *) *p) = malloc(sizeof(NoArv));` and `((NoArv *)*p)->info = MALLOC(sizeof(Student));` to tell the compiler to use the `void *` that `p` points to should be used as  a pointer to `NoArv`

Comment: It looks sort of like an attempt at a generic tree implementation, with the student tree being one specific derived type. But if that's the case it's been done wrong. A struct with left and right pointers *after* the node data can't be used with a single tree implementation because the offset of the left and right pointers depends on the size of the node data. (Unless you store the offsets as metadata with each tree... and that's just ugly)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No need to cast for the allocation.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem , using your sugestion I get this error:

`base.c:46:18: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

`((NoArv *) *p) = MALLOC(sizeof(NoArv));`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley , it IS exactly an attempt at a generic tree implementation. 
But as I said before, I cannot change the definitions of Student neither NoArv structs.

If the **p** is initially pointing to **NULL**, I sholud allocate a new node. if not, there will be an value assigned to p->info.ra so I (think I) can compare it to a.ra and just follow the proper side of the tree.

Comment: @Kaiser: You don't need to cast `*p` when you call `malloc`, as pointed out by Joachim

Comment: Not a very good generic if you have to mention the name of the derived type in the implementation of the base type...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you've `typedef`d `Base` as `void *`, so a function argument of type `Base *` is not a `void *` - it's a `void **`. `void *` is a generic pointer, but `void **` is not, so you'll want to fix that.

Second, you have to cast or otherwise convert a `void *` to the appropriate type before dereferencing it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void * Base; 
typedef char * String;

typedef struct {
    int ra;
    String name;
} Student;

void change_student(Base p)
{
    Student * s = p;
    s->ra = 8;
    s->name = "Legs on a spider";
}

void print_student(Base p)
{
    Student * s = p;
    printf("%d, %s\n", s->ra, s->name);
}

int main(void)
{
    Student my_student = {42, "Meaning of life"};
    print_student(&my_student);
    change_student(&my_student);
    print_student(&my_student);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./void
42, Meaning of life
8, Legs on a spider
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

If you need pointers to pointers, for instance to `malloc()` some memory for a node as you suggest in your comments, then something like `Student **` can be converted to `void *` just as well as `Student *` can, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void * Base; 
typedef char * String;

typedef struct {
    int ra;
    String name;
} Student;

void change_student(Base p)
{
    Student * s = *((Student **) p);
    if ( s ) {
        s->ra = 8;
        s->name = "Legs on a spider";
    }
    else {
        Student * new_student = malloc(sizeof *new_student);
        if ( !new_student ) {
            perror("couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        new_student->ra = 4;
        new_student->name = "Horsemen of the Apocalypse";
        *((Student **) p) = new_student;
    }
}

void print_student(Base p)
{
    Student * s = p;
    printf("%d, %s\n", s->ra, s->name);
}

int main(void)
{
    Student my_student = {42, "Meaning of life"};
    Student * pstudent = &my_student;
    print_student(pstudent);
    change_student(&pstudent);
    print_student(pstudent);

    Student * nstudent = NULL;
    change_student(&nstudent);
    print_student(nstudent);

    free(nstudent);

    return 0;
}
```

yielding:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./void2
42, Meaning of life
8, Legs on a spider
4, Horsemen of the Apocalypse
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Paul, your code sugestion completelly removes NoArv structure. **p** should point to a **NoArv** structure and not to a **Student** structure. 
But I get the general idea and it worked!
Thanks.

Comment: @Kaiser: Yes, that was deliberate, I was trying to answer your actual question about "the proper way to refer to a struct through a void pointer", not trying to implement the program you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

I used Paul Griffiths idea and get this code. 
But that is NOT working. As Griffiths noted in comments, it is just leaking memory.

```
Boolean InsertBase(Base *p, Student a) {

  ImplBase s = *p;

  while(s != NULL){
    if(a.ra < s->info.ra)
      s = s->left;
    else if(a.ra > s->info.ra)
      s = s->right;
    else
      return false;
  }

  s = MALLOC(sizeof(NoArv));
  s->info.ra = a.ra;
  s->info.name = a.name;

  s->left = s->right = NULL;

  return true;

}
```

Comment: That's just going to leak memory, the address you store in `s` will be discarded at the end of the function, since `s` is a local variable.